# $57$ companies. $10$ displayed at random. Probability of being displayed?

Tags: probability

1. In my industry our clients are presented with $10$ companies from a possible $57$ to select and send work to. They only choose $1$.

What is the probability that a company is displayed in the $10$ shown to the client?

My attempt:  $\dfrac{10}{57}$

2. Another group of companies are in a separate pot and $2$ are displayed from a possible $10$. What is the probability that a company is displayed in the $2$ shown to the client?

Apologies if this appears basic or I have failed to include any relevant information - I have no idea where to begin!

Comment: Well, what **definition** of "probability" are you using?  The standard is that ir there are n possible outcomes, all equally likely, then the probability the outcome is one of a subset containing m of those outcomes is m/n.

Comment: Yes I would be using standard definition. So the answer would be 10/57 = 0.1754 ?

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.   You can use the same method to solve the second question.